# Ubuntu laptop won't recognize external HDMI monitor with VGA adapter for more than a minute

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a Lenovo laptop with a **Nvidia Geforce GT 730m** video board, which have an external HDMI port. I also own an external Samsung monitor, which I don't know the model of. It only has VGA input.

To solve that issue, I bought a VGA to HDMI adapter, like this one:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and this is a fresh install (I formatted to try to fix the issue). My problem is: **The laptop isn't recognizing the HDMI monitor for more than 1 minute**.

However, there is one small catch to this issue: Right after I plug the HDMI in, it is recognized, and I can use it for some time. After sometime passes, it seems to reconfigure and the monitor is gone. If I try to `xrandr` while it's working, it also loses configuration and is gone. The same happens if I try any configuration with Displays or Nvidia XServer, it just disappears when the Displays software loads

I tried almos everything I could find, but nothing worked. Including:

1. `xrandr --addmode` and some variations
2. Using NVidia latest drivers
3. Using Nouveau latest drivers
4. Formatting the OS
5. Logging in with `nomodeset` and `noedid` (the combination of both rendered no interface, not even in the notebook screen)

My Kernel version is 4.15.0-42-generic

Comment: Yes, I do get a picture on display for some time after I plug it in. Configuring makes it go away

Comment: If the adapter isn't active (and thus requires power), it very likely won't work unless  it's specifically suitable for some non-standard "_VGA-over-HDMI_" output mode. Does a normal HDMI (or DVI) monitor work?

Comment: The monitor stops working after some time it is plugged in, and then xrandr gives me `HDMI-1 (disconnected)`

Comment: If I reconnect it works again, but ytring to verify anything with `xrandr` makes it go away before any output in xrandr

Comment: I'm unsure if normal HDMi monitor works, I don't have one. This is the only monitor I own